# Extract tables from Word (.docx) to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to extract tables that exist in a Word file and copy/paste them in an Excel file. I tried to write a VBA macro to do this using the "while...Wend" but the program shows an error in `While WordDoc.Table(i) <> 0` I dont know why, im not an experience VBA coder. Please if you have a solution help me!

```
Sub copieTableauWordVersExcel()
'nécéssite d'activer la référence Microsoft Word xx.x Object Library

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim Fichier As String
Dim i As Integer

'le document Word est supposé fermé avant le lancement de la macro
Fichier = "C:\Users\429093\Desktop\ME.docx" 'adapter le chemin
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 'creation session Word

WordApp.Visible = False 'pour que word reste masqué pendant l'opération
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Fichier) 'ouverture du fichier Word

i = 1

While WordDoc.Table(i) <> 0
   WordDoc.Tables(i).Range.Copy 'copie du tableau Word
   'dans Word chaque tableau est indexé
   'ici l'index est à 2 car le premier index correspond au cadre autour du titre du
   'document Word
   i = i + 1
Wend

Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste 'collage des données dans Excel
WordDoc.Close False 'ferme le document Word sans sauvegarde
WordApp.Quit 'ferme l'application Word

End Sub
```

Comment: if the question not clear, please ask me

Comment: For starters it should be `.Tables(i)`. But the collection of tables returns a table, not a number so you should not comparing it to zero.

Comment: @KostasK. ok but i meant by <>0 that  it will stop when there is no more tables to copy... what should i do in this case?

Comment: Try a `For` loop: `For i = 0 To WordDoc.Tables.Count - 1 [...] Next i`.

Comment: Does the solution need to use VBA? It can be done very easily with R for which there is a package called 'docxtractr'. I will add more if this is of interest.

Comment: See, for example: https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?8900-Help-with-VBA-to-extract-data-from-Word-to-Excel&p=36586&viewfull=1#post36586 & https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/showthread.php?8900-Help-with-VBA-to-extract-data-from-Word-to-Excel&p=36594&viewfull=1#post36594

Answer (score 0):

Your code had two problems. First what you have does not pick up all tables in the document and two you are only going to paste the results into one cell in the Excel document. That means even if you had a proper loop executing and copying all tables, they'd each be pasted over the top of the other in the worksheet.

Try something like this ...

```
For i = 1 to WordDoc.Tables.Count
    WordDoc.Tables(i).Range.Copy
    Range("A" & i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
```

Comment: Hello, fisrt i would like to thank you all for your help.So, i tried to modify my code based on your suggestions, finally i get the code below: (i used the loop if to copy all the tables i have one under the other)but it doesnt work very well(my objectif is to copy past all the tabels i have in my word file  to my excel file)

Comment: Sub FF()
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim Fichier As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Fichier = "ME\ME1.docx"
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application") 
WordApp.Visible = False
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Fichier)
j = 1
If Cells(j, 1).Value = 0 Then
For i = 1 To WordDoc.Tables.Count
    WordDoc.Tables(i).Range.Copy
    Cells(j, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
Else: j = j + 1
End If

WordDoc.Close False
WordApp.Quit 
End Sub